# form validation set_message not showing any error in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I am new to codeigniter. I have created a login page now I want to show an error message that login details are wrong or invalid login, if the user enter wrong credentials. i dont know where i am doing wrong but when i enter wrong credentials the page is refreshed without any error message

```
function login_user() {
  // Create an instance of the user model
  $this->load->model('user_m');

  // Grab the email and password from the form POST
  $username= $this->input->post('username');
  $pass  = $this->input->post('password');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');
  $this->load->helper('security');
  if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
      $this->load->view('login');
  }

  if( $username && $pass && $this->user_m->validate_user($username,$pass)) {
      // If the user is valid, redirect to the main view
      redirect('/dashboard');
  } else {
      // Otherwise show the login screen with an error message.
      $this->form_validation->set_message('login_user','Wrong email, password combination.');
        $this->load->view('login');
  }
```

}

in my view i am using the following line to show errors

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

the "user name and password field is required" error is working fine but invalid login is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is `ELSE` section on last of the code snippet. so you have write something like this.

## Short definition

```
$this->form_validation->set_message()
```

Only work when the validation rules may failed. So i assume that you input the `username` and `password` wrong but you fill for `required` logic. so `form_validation` pass this test case.
so change `$this->form_validation->set_message()` to following:

Replace

```
if( $username && $pass && $this->user_m->validate_user($username,$pass)) {
  // If the user is valid, redirect to the main view
  redirect('/dashboard');
} else {
  // Otherwise show the login screen with an error message.
  $this->form_validation->set_message('login_user','Wrong email, password combination.');
    $this->load->view('login');
}
```

to

```
if( $username && $pass && $this->user_m->validate_user($username,$pass)) {

      // If the user is valid, redirect to the main view
      redirect('/dashboard');

  } else {

      // Otherwise show the login screen with an error message.

      $this->session->set_flashdata('authError', 'Username or Password Invalid !!');
      $this->load->view('login');
  }
```

And on the `VIEW` page write something like this:

replace

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

to

```
<?php if( $this->session->flashdata('authError') )
{
   echo $this->session->flashdata('authError');
}?>
```